# FTDI2232H mini module GPIO, LED not Blinking

Tags: python, pyserial, ftdi

I am trying to read and write in FTDI2232H mini module. I have 3 GPIO signal 1 input and 2 output. I tried to set the Pin to High and Low . But it is not working. I connected a LED to check and LED is not blinking.

```
import serial

class FTDI2232H:
    # Define the bit masks for each pin
    Signal1= 0x10 # AD4 (input)
    Signal2= 0x20  # AD5 (output)
    Signal3= 0x80  # AD6 (input)

    def __init__(self, port="COM7", baudrate=6000000):
        self.serial = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=baudrate)

        # Configure the pins as inputs or outputs
        # self.set_pin_direction(self.Signal1, 'in')  # Set Signal1 pin as an input
        self.set_pin_direction(self.Signal2, 'out')  # Set Signal2 pin as an output
        self.set_pin_direction(self.Signal3, 'out')  # Set Signal3 pin as an output


    '''RTS-Request to send; DTR (Data Terminal Ready);RI (Ring Indicator) 
     The set_pin_direction function sets the direction of a pin to either input or output. 
     If the pin is set to input, the function checks the state of the RI line to determine 
     whether to set the pin to RTS or DTR. If the pin is set to output, the function sets the 
     state of the RTS or DTR line depending on the pin and value parameters passed in.'''

    def set_pin_direction(self, pin, direction):
        if direction == 'in':
            raise ValueError("Invalid pin direction. Pin must be set to 'out'.")

        elif direction == 'out':
            # Set pin as output if not already set
            if pin == self.Signal1:
                self.serial.setRTS(0)
            else:
                if pin == self.Signal3:
                    self.serial.setRTS(0)
                else:
                    self.serial.setDTR(0)

        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid pin direction. Must be 'in' or 'out'.")

    '''The read_pin function reads the state of the RI line, which has been set to the 
    pin direction of input, and then sets the pin direction back to output 
    before returning the value.'''
    def read_pin(self, pin):
        # Set the pin direction to input
        self.set_pin_direction(pin, 'in')

        # Read the pin value
        value = self.serial.getRI()   # get the state of the RI line

        # Set the pin direction back to output
        self.set_pin_direction(pin, 'out')

        return value
    '''The write_pin function sets the pin direction to output, sets the state
     of the RTS or DTR line based on the pin and value parameters passed in, 
     and then sets the pin direction back to output.'''
    def write_pin(self, pin, value):
        # Set the pin direction to output
        self.set_pin_direction(pin, 'out')

        # Set the pin value
        if value:
            if pin == self.Sgnal3:
                self.serial.setRTS(1)
            else:
                self.serial.setDTR(1)
        else:
            if pin == self.Signal3:
                self.serial.setRTS(0)
            else:
                self.serial.setDTR(0)

        # Set the pin direction back to output
        self.set_pin_direction(pin, 'out')

    def close(self):
        self.serial.close()
```

And the main code

```
import time
from lib_led import FTDI2232H


def main():
    print("Creating FTDI2232H object")
    ftdi = FTDI2232H()
    ftdi.set_pin_direction(FTDI2232H.Signal2, 'out')

    try:
        ftdi.write_pin(FTDI2232H.Signal2, 0)  # Set Signal2 pin to 0 (low)
        while True:
            ftdi.write_pin(FTDI2232H.Signal2, 1)  # Set Signal 2 pin to 1 (high)
            print("I am HIGH")
            time.sleep(1)  # Delay for half a second
            ftdi.write_pin(FTDI2232H.Signal2, 0)  # Remove this line
            print("I am LOW")
            time.sleep(1)  # Delay for half a second
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    ftdi.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Help me solve this. Here is the code. I connected my LED to CN2-13 pin of FTDI2232H mini module.

I expect the LED to glow when high and off when low. But for both the output pins, I don't see the LED blinking/glowing. But for the input pin of Signal1, The LED is glowing when its LOW and stops when its High

Comment: Maybe the LED is broken?

Comment: No the led is working, I checked for the input pin and it is perfectly toggling

Comment: You mean that the pin is toggling but the LED does not light up?

Comment: No I mean for the Signal1 which is a input pin I can toggle the LED. But When I try it for Signal 2 and 3 the LED is not toggling at all

Comment: Are you mixing up "input" and "output"? How can you toggle the LED that is connected to an input pin? If you can toggle it, it's an output pin.

Comment: I changed the input pin into output and tried